# Gson not parsing JSON in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I'm trying to parse a string that contains JSON information using the GSON library. I get this string from an HttpRequest that works fine (I can print it in the console and works fine). The problem seems to come from this line:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(inputLine,JsonObject.class).getAsJsonObject();
```

The string is in "inputLine" btw. The compiler says 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson 
and points at that line. Here's the JSON I'm trying to read if thats somehow helpful:

```
{
   "meta":{
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "interval": "1min",
      "currency": "USD",
      "exchange_timezone": "America/New_York",
      "exchange": "NASDAQ",
      "type": "Common Stock"
   },
   "values":[
      {
         "datetime":"2019-08-09 15:59:00",
         "open":"200.93999",
         "high":"201.25599",
         "low":"200.85199",
         "close":"201.05000",
         "volume":"472287"
      },
      {
         "datetime":"2019-08-09 15:58:00",
         "open":"201.02999",
         "high":"201.13000",
         "low":"200.83999",
         "close":"200.93499",
         "volume":"209854"
      },
      {
         "datetime":"2019-08-09 15:57:00",
         "open":"201.02000",
         "high":"201.07000",
         "low":"200.91000",
         "close":"201.02000",
         "volume":"149032"
      },
      {
         "datetime":"2019-08-09 15:56:00",
         "open":"201.11999",
         "high":"201.25999",
         "low":"201.03340",
         "close":"201.03340",
         "volume":"178892"
      },
      {
         "datetime":"2019-08-09 15:55:00",
         "open":"201.75999",
         "high":"201.75999",
         "low":"201.07000",
         "close":"201.13000",
         "volume":"372886"
      },
      {...}
   ],
   "status":"ok"
}
```

I want the close values of every object inside the array "values". I tried this but, again, can't figure out what is the mistake here

```
   XYSeries jsonSerie = new XYSeries("Tiempo");
        JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(inputLine,JsonObject.class).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonArr = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("values");
        int i = 0;
        do{
            JsonObject jObj = jsonArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonElement jElem = jObj.get("close");
            BigDecimal close = jElem.getAsBigDecimal();
            jsonSerie.add(i, close);
            i++;
        }
        while(i < jsonArr.size());
        oDataSet = new XYSeriesCollection();
        oDataSet.addSeries(jsonSerie);
```

Any ideas on how to do this or where's the mistake? (Oh also I'm using the JFreeChart and JCommon libs to graph this values, thats where the XY things come from)

Comment: Ups I just saw I messed up the title, it meant to say "not parsing" :(

Comment: ... you can edit the question multiple times.

Comment: You need to make a Gson Serializable class first

Comment: Is Gson dependency added to your application?

Comment: Yes: it sounds like a classpath issue

Comment: "You need to make a Gson Serializable class first" what is that? I have Gson added as a jar library and imported com.google.gson.*; is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: "it sounds like a classpath issue" Any idea on how to fix that if that's the case?